# Loop through nested JSON array

Tags: java, json

I have a JSON response that looks like this:

```
{
    "1":{
        "id":"1",
        "user_id":"1",
        "children":[
            {
                "id":"2",
                "user_id":"2",
                "children":[
                    {
                        "id":"3",
                        "user_id":"3",
                        "children":[
                            {
                                "id":"4",
                                "user_id":"2",
                                "children":[

                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "id":"5",
                        "user_id":"1",
                        "children":[

                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id":"6",
                "user_id":"2",
                "children":[

                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "7":{
        "id":"7",
        "user_id":"2",
        ...
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have nested arrays (`children`). I need to loop through this JSON response, going through each nested array until it runs into an empty `children` array, and then takes a step back to continue to the rest of the items.

I made a model class for the response, so my current code looks like this:

```
for (Post post : postResponse.getData()) {
    //
}
```

Which obviously only iterates through the top-level items (id `1` and `7` in my case).

How can I do this?

Comment: Any reason not to just use Jackson and have a `List<Person> children` on a `Person` class?

Comment: I bet there are a dozen of duplicated questions around...

Comment: please post bit more code you tried.will helpful to extend help

Answer (score 1):

you need a recursive function.

```
function iterateTree(object) {
  if (!object) { //recursion stop criteria || you need to implement what your stop criteria is
     return;
  }
  //doSomthingWithObject();
  iterateTree(object.children);
}
```

I'm sure you figure it out how to use it in java.

Answer (score 0):

You may try

```
        public void printJsonObject(JSONObject jsonObj) {
            for (String keyStr : jsonObj.keySet()) {
                Object keyvalue = jsonObj.get(keyStr);

                //Print key and value
                System.out.println("key: "+ keyStr + " value: " + keyvalue);

                //for nested objects iteration if required
                if (keyvalue instanceof JSONObject)
                    printJsonObject((JSONObject)keyvalue);
            }

        }
```